# What is the term for finding words within words for comedic effect?

Tags: puns

I am trying to find a word that describes *finding a word within another word* for **comedic effect** i.e. functioning as a pun or word play.

The example that sparked this question was when I came across a product name written on the box for hair regrowth in men. The text was **"Hair A-Gain"**.

In this example, the noun/verb *gain* can be found within the adverb *again*; it is clever because it refers to two separate but related ideas → having hair once more as well as the act of "gaining" more hair.

What is the correct term for this phenomenon of finding words within words for comedic effect?

**EDIT:** Follow up question → what is simply the correct term describing the phenomenon of finding words within words?

Comment: I would say it's a form of punning or word play.

Answer (score 1):

It is a "**play-on-words**" or "**word play**". It is a formal form of "**wit**", though here no pun intended. Another form of it might be a "**pun**", in this case, pun intended.

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+on+words

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_play

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pun

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=no%20pun%20intended